# How do I fix the error of my django form not having cleaned_data attribute?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

I have this form:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1",
                  "pass"]
```

And this View:

```
def register(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(req.POST)
        print('yaml')
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("/home")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        form.save()
        return render(req, "users/register.html", {"form":form})
```

But when I visit the url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.urls")),
    path('register/', userViews.register, name="register"),
    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /register/
....
AttributeError: 'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

Please I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `form.save()` in case of a GET request: you can only save an object in case it is bounded and valid, so:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # only redirect when the POST is successful
            return redirect('home')  # 🖘 use the name of a view
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()  # no form.save()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing, `pass` is no field in inbuilt `User` model, there are two fields related to passwords which are `password1` and `password2`, unless and until you haven't changed it in original django code.

There no need for redirection, please remove `form.save()` in else condition.